# Image reconstruction from k-space data

Tags: reconstruction

I have k-space data related to an image. k-space data is made of Kx, Ky, signal arrays of 4100x1. What I have done for image reconstruction is:

$$I_{m,n}=\sum_i Signal_i \space e^{2\pi j(\frac{K_{x}^i \space m}{4100} + \frac{K_{y}^i \space n}{4100}) } $$

However, I cannot reconstruct the image correctly. What do you think is the mistake? Thanks in advance!